# Is Youtube API licensed?

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We are planning to use youtube APIs in one of our applications. Is there any pricing applicable for consuming Youtube APIs ? Any there any kinds of limits that developer need to be aware ?

Please point to any documentation resources.

Thanks
MAdhu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the most part the YouTube api is free to use.  You should be aware of the usage quota and calculate what you need [Quota cost](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost)  The YouTube API is cost based so each request you make has a cost against your quota.

You can request an extension to your quota but i suggest you do it early as it can take time to get a quota extension.

You have not mentioned what your app is doing but if you are using Oauth2 in order to access private user data your app will need to go though the verification process [verification](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/7454865?hl=en) Until your app has been verified you may only have 100 users authorize your application, and any videos uploaded by your application will be set to private.

Start the verification process early it can take a lot of time.